# How to combine 2 free Google App accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have 2 free Google App accounts. One with 10 limited users (phudien.vn) and one with 50 limited users (phudienltd.com). Is it possible to combine the two accounts so that I could create 50 emails with the `@phudien.vn` extension?

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps (Free) can have up to a maximum of 10 users ([source](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html)), so if you already have 10 users on it, you can't migrate more users to it. You can, however, upgrade it to [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html), where you can have an unlimited number of users (but it's not free), and migrate all your users from the other account to it.

PS: Are you sure the 50 users account is free? It sure seems to be [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html), which is not free.

Comment: At one time is was 50 free. I have an account that squeaked under the deadline.

Comment: Yes, back to the old time, google apps was free with unlimited users :-J

Answer (score 1):

No. You can migrate users & data from one account to other, but you can't combine them.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to migrate data between the two Google accounts, you can try https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?query=migration+free+domain at Google marketplace.

Comment: That doesn't answer the OP's questions. The question was how to `combine` the two accounts not migrate data